# room database with list inside an object

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Till this time I was only doing sql queries which had only simple types or objects where annotation `@Embedded` was doing a job. Currently I have to extend my sql query to receive "simple data" in the list inside.

```
data class SimpleDataClass(
@Embedded val myObject: MyObject,
val id: UUID,
val listOfNumbers: List<MyNumbers>)
```

where

```
data class MyNumbers( val number: Int)
```

How to do this? By sql statement? Somehow with code? In DAO I return a:
`LiveData<List<SimpleDataClass>>`

When I try to receive data as before I get:

> Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an >empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by >name and type). - java.util.List

Comment: your question is little unclear about what you want to ask, please try to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide very few information about your problem, but I think that `Room relations` is what you need. See this article [Database relations with Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542), should be helpful.